# Transmit large data through UART OR Ethernet

Tags: stm32, uart, ethernet, nucleo

I followed the [AN4666](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4666-parallel-synchronous-transmission-using-gpio-and-dma-stmicroelectronics.pdf) to read data from GPIOC ports triggered by timer input capture mode and save into a large buffer of uint8 in size of (510000) arrays,  all I want to do is to transmit the full buffer after the reading operations is complete to my pc.
I have tried transmitting it through UART but I realized that the maximum size I can transmit is 65535 bytes before it stops. also if I used circular mode the the pointer will start from the beginning.

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define MAX_FRAME_SIZE 458745 
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tim1_ch1;
 
UART_HandleTypeDef huart3;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart3_tx;
 
PCD_HandleTypeDef hpcd_USB_OTG_FS;
 
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
const uint8_t aFull_Buffer[MAX_FRAME_SIZE];
/* USER CODE END PD */
int main(void)
{
htim1.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1]->XferCpltCallback = TransferComplete;
// Start DMA in interrupt mode, specify source and destination
    HAL_DMA_Start_IT(htim1.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_CC1], GPIOC_IDR, (uint32_t) &aFull_Buffer, MAX_FRAME_SIZE);
    // Enable timer to trigger DMA transfer - CC1DE bit
    __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_DMA(&htim1, TIM_DMA_CC1);
    // Enable timer input capture
    HAL_TIM_IC_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
while (1) {
}}
static void TransferComplete(DMA_HandleTypeDef *hdma_tim1_ch1) {
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3,aFull_Buffer,MAX_FRAME_SIZE );
}
```

I was able to receive only 65535 bytes because I know that (max size of transmit function is 16 bits= 65535)

1. Can I do multiple uart transmissions but with different starting points
   from my buffer?
2. Is there a way to transmit data through Ethernet ?

Comment: Yes and yes. Why do you need to use dma to transmit the data? You can simply write some code send the data via the uart byte by byte. More conventionally, you would frame the data in packets and have a CRC to ensure the data is received correctly. Something like Xmodem protocol. As for ethernet, you would usually have a tcp/ip stack and maybe a web server to transfer the data as a file.

Comment: I have thought of this where I can separate my aFull_Buffer into for example 5 DATA buffers each is 65535 bytes in size then transmit each one of them, unfortunately using it this way will put some  constrains  on the MAX_FRAME_SIZE that I can use because of RAM_D1 size, my main goal is to have the buffer as maximum as I can so I can do some processing on it, 
as for the Ethernet do u have any examples that I can use in NUCLEO-h743ZI2 board.

Comment: maybe send 65535 bytes and then 65535 more bytes and then 65535 more bytes and then 65535 more bytes and then 65535 more bytes and then 65535 more bytes and then 65535 more bytes and then 51255 more bytes